# Why can't I use my internal microphone at the same time as my headphones?

Tags: audio, microphone, realtek-hd-audio

I have a Samsung Series 7 NP700-Z5A, which has a dual-purpose mic/headphone jack.

In both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, whenever I plug in my headphones the internal mic goes completely dead. When the headphones aren't plugged in, the microphone is fine.

The hardware is Realtek HD audio and the driver version 6.0.1.6428 (on Windows, at least).

I have an inkling that it thinks my headphones are a microphone, but there seems to be no option (in either OS) to adjust this.

Why can't I use my laptop's internal microphone while my headphones are plugged in?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix the internal microphone in Realtek HD Audio Manager:

1. Open *Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → Realtek HD Audio Manager*.

   [image: Control Panel]
2. In Realtek Audio Manager, select "Device advanced settings" in the top right.

   [image: Realtek HD Audio Manager]
3. Select "Separate all input jacks as independent devices" and click OK.

   (*If you don't see an option to separate jacks, you may need to update your Realtek Audio drivers.*)

   [image: Device advanced settings]
4. Open *Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → Sound → Recording*
5. Set your internal microphone as the default recording device.

   [image: Recording devices]

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill My apologies. I will go back and raise duplicate flags to this question, as I cannot vote to close without an upvoted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an answer since I was having the same issue. I'm using an Asus VivoBook with Windows 11, and whenever I plugged earphones or headphones into my computer, the computer's microphone stopped working - even if my earphones had no microphone!

Once my headphones or earphones are plugged in, there is a window that pops up for the *Realtek Audio Console* app. If this doesn't pop up for you, you can just search for it and open it (it came pre-installed on my computer). Then, navigate to the "Device Advanced Settings" tab. Under "Connector Retasking", you have the option of selecting whether you just plugged in a Headphone, a Headset, "Mic In", or "Speaker Out". For me, the default setting was "Headset", which meant that the computer thought my device would have its own microphone. If you switch it to "Headphone", then the computer goes back to using its own microphone.

[image]