# Laptop built-in microphone does not work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I have trouble using the mic input of my [Dell Inspiron 3542](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3542-laptop/overview) laptop, which is out of warranty (so no Dell support).

When I use any application requiring a mic, there is no input from the built-in microphone. I have also plugged in two different headsets with a 3.5mm jack but neither one worked.

I have gone through all of the steps mentioned on troubleshooting websites (e.g. [this one](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-fix-a-microphone-not-working-on-windows-10/) and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/395296/fix-my-microphone-doesnt-work-on-windows-10/)). I am so desperate that I even tried [Microsoft help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034886/accessories-headset-troubleshooting-microphone-issues).

Also, I noticed that if I put my finger on the tiny hole, above the monitor where mic is installed, an echoing sound starts to come. If I tap my finger on it, it does recognize some tap sound.

I also uninstalled the mic from Device Manager, updated the driver, ran Windows update and have updated BIOS and other drivers using Dell Support.

So at this point, I am completely out of ideas of troubleshooting.

However, I did notice that when I plug in a headset through USB, the headset mic records audio fine.

---

I have already checked these questions:

- [Built-in microphone not working with desktop apps on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1520141/274076)
- [Use laptop microphone when headset is plugged in, not use headset mic](https://superuser.com/q/682271/274076)
- *and a bunch of others on this site*

Comment: @K7AAY Out of warranty and do not want to give $100 to Dell.

Comment: 1) Can you use a Bluetooth audio source, such as a Bluetooth headset, and test recording audio from it? 2) Does it work if you make a Linux LiveUSB and test with a different OS? 3) Can you get a very small light source (like a single LED on a battery or bore scope light) , put it up to the audio jack, and see if there's a foreign object in there? https://www.amazon.com/Scope-Flexible-Light-Chamber-Inspection/dp/B00DE7M2YS  or https://www.wish.com/product/5d63a3925f4d531cba172e59?

Comment: Linux LiveUSB: Download MATE or Xubuntu from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Check for download errors by following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on your Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 then reboot and choose the USB Flash Drive to boot from.