# Built in microphone will not work when apple earbuds are plugged in

Tags: windows-10, audio, lenovo-laptop, microphone

Whenever I plug in my apple earbuds, *without a microphone*, the built in computer microphone will not work. Several questions similar to mine, such as: [Why can't I use my internal microphone at the same time as my headphones?](https://superuser.com/questions/455362/why-cant-i-use-my-internal-microphone-at-the-same-time-as-my-headphones), do not work with my current laptop (lenovo flex 515).